# Conversion of loops to Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am writing this logic where I am assigning individual rooms to each employee, the code of which i am pasting below :

```
public List<EmployeeRooms> assignRoomEmployee(Request request) {
    List<Employee> allEmployeeList = getAllEmployeeList(request);
    int possibleAssigments = Math.min(request.getRooms().size(), allEmployeeList.size());        
    List<EmployeeRooms> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < possibleAssigments) {                                         
     for (int j= 0; j < allEmployeeList.size(); j++) {                       
         finalList.add(createRoomEmployeeList(allEmployeeList.get(j), request.getRooms().get(i)));                                       
         i++;
         }          
    }
    return finalList;
    
}
```

Now I would like to write this loop logic using a single Java streams statement but not I have been able to do so correctly, I tried this below code but it assigns each room to each employee thus creating duplicates instead of each room to individual employee:

```
 while(i < possibleAssigments) {             
     allEmployeeList.stream()
                    .map(emp -> createRoomEmployeeList(emp, request.getRooms().get(i)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
     i++;
 }
```

Comment: I think your original method is not written correctly. If the employee list is longer than the list of rooms, it will fail. If you are trying to do a zip operation, there should only be one loop.

Comment: Yes you are right @RealSkeptic, I have updated the code accordingly for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IntStream()` to loop between `i` and `possibleAssigments` then return a `RoomEmployeeList` for each iteration:

```
x -> createRoomEmployeeList(allEmployeeList.get(x), request.getRooms().get(x)))
```

and finally collect them.

I didn't tested but it should be something like this:

```
finalList = IntStream.range(i, possibleAssigments).boxed().map(
                x -> createRoomEmployeeList(allEmployeeList.get(x), request.getRooms().get(x)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `assignRoomEmployee()` method:

```
public List<EmployeeRooms> assignRoomEmployee(Request request) {
    List<Employee> allEmployeeList = getAllEmployeeList(request);
    int possibleAssigments = Math.min(request.getRooms().size(), allEmployeeList.size());
    int i = 0;
    
    List<EmployeeRooms> finalList = IntStream.range(i, possibleAssigments).boxed().map(
            x -> createRoomEmployeeList(allEmployeeList.get(x), request.getRooms().get(x)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return finalList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake I see is that you don't save the result of this stream action in a variable.

This should probably be

```java
 List<EmployeeRooms> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
 while(i < possibleAssigments) {             
     finalList.addAll(allEmployeeList.stream().map(emp -> createRoomEmployeeList(emp, request.getRooms().get(i))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
     i++;
 }
```

Comment: you might mean `finalList.addAll`

Comment: Yeah you're right. Didn't think long enough about that

Comment: Well, now it's just a cartesian product of the rooms and employee lists which doesn't have the limit set in the original code.

Comment: @Naman actually OP current implementation confusing, OP just want assign room to employee and their mapping objects as list.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks True. I have cast a close vote for the requirement of details and clarity for that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

To assign room to employee

- Iterate 0 to `possibleAssigments-1`
- Get employee `allEmployeeList.get(i)` and room `request.getRooms().get(i)`
- create `EmployeeRooms`

Using Stream API you can do this way.

```
List<EmployeeRooms> finalList = 
    IntStream.range(0, possibleAssigments)
             .boxed()
             .map(i -> createRoomEmployeeList(allEmployeeList.get(i),
                                              request.getRooms().get(i)))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```